# After change usrname "root" to "%" , I can't connect to mysql server any more

Tags: mysql

In order to allow remotely connect to mysql . Instead of changing the host name "localhost" to "%" I mistaked changed the username "root" to "%" and restarted mysql 
service. Now I can not login to mysql locally or remotely any more . How to solve this issue? Thanks in
advance!

Answer (score 1):

You probably made a mistake updating security.

You can restart MySQL without any authentication and re-connect to see what went wrong:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-grant-tables

NOTE: You need to do this from the server that is running MySQL.

If you need help understanding what is wrong with the security configuration, post the contents of the relevant authentication tables (but don't post your password hash, as a valid password can be re-constructed from the hash).

Comment: I installed lampp on my server . How to restarted mysql service separately?

Comment: I just restarted mysql service with option --skip-grant-tables . And connect to mysql without username and passwd . This time shows the following error: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)  . I really don't know how to solve this while I am new to mysql

Answer (score 1):

If you changed the username, you need to login using "%" not root. You want to change the host field, not user field. Usually you want to grant remote logins fewer permissions. For example, remote logins would not have "DROP" privileges.

The same login/password combo can have different privileges depending on where they login from. Think of the user name as the name + host they are logging in from.

Comment: But I am confused that I can not login to the mysql with username "%". I that because mysql treated "%" as a special character?

Comment: % is a wildcard character in the host, but it's not for the user name.  Not sure what you did.